# How can I save an array to the database?

Tags: php, arrays, database

I am facing some problem in my college project. I am to build an Online shopping website using php. Here, I used Session array `$_SESSION['cart_array']` where I stored product id and quantity. The code works fine and my cart is working.

Now I am to save the user order to a database table `order`. I planned to to use the product Id and quantity from `order` table to generate a bill. Now, the problem is how to store those id and quantity in database under one unique Id(Order Id)?

I am new to php and I am not sure if my approach is appropriate. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: you could:http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

Comment: With this level of detail in your description, nobody can answer because its not clear what you are really asking about.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I will try to provide any info required. This is my first time asking a question here. So, sorry for being unclear again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since data is flat in a relational database, you often need multiple tables to get the required structure.

In this case you need a second table called `order_product` with a combined primary key of the fields `order_id` and `product_id` and an additional column `quantity`. You might want to add a `price` field as well.

So first you save the general information to the `order` table, than you save the ordered products to the `order_product` table.

To make sure you don't get a partial order when an error occurs, do `START TRANSACTION` before the first `INSERT` query and `COMMIT` after the last query. See [MySQL Transactions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html) for more info on that.

Comment: Thanks. Will try this for sure.

Comment: @ratulkeot Please accept the answer (green check mark) if you're satisfied with the answer.